# Calling textfield from another class swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, class

**called class:**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController { 
    let chipField: UITextField = {
        ........

        return textField1
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(chipField)

    }
}
```

**table to be called:**

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    ....
}
```

`MainTableViewController` call `chipfield` in `LoginViewController`

Comment: What is the relationship between MainTableViewController and LoginViewController?

Comment: Mainview class opens when I login with loginview @BenOng

Comment: Can you add in the chunk of codes where you init and "open" MainTableViewController?

Comment: @objc func handleLogin(){
        
        
        
        let email = emailField.text
        let password = passwordField.text
        let chip = chipField.text
        
        
        
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email!, password: password!, completion: { (user, err) in   
                if let user = user{
   
                    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainTableViewController()) self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: {
   }) } }) }}
    
    
    
    
}

Comment: Please do not comment codes like that, there is an Edit function where you can add it into your question so others who may have better answers can also see it easily and in a more legible format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your situation all you need is just a property in MainTableViewController

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var chipFieldCopy:UITextField?
    ...
}
```

But I would suggest you rethink if you need the entire UITextField, in most situation you will only need it's text so

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var chipInfoString:String?
    ...
}
```

Is enough.

In your handleLogin() method, you can pass it into MainTableViewController like:

```
//let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainTableViewController()) //Replace this line

let mainTableVC = MainTableViewController()
mainTableVC.chipFieldCopy = chipField
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTableVC)
```

or like I suggest

```
mainTableVC.chipInfoString = chipField.text
```

and you can access it in MainTableViewController

Comment: handleLogin() error //Value of type 'MainTableViewController' has no member 'chipInfoString'

Comment: You have to add that property to MainTableViewController... see the first half of my answer

Comment: Okey,thanks. working code. I would like to assign this value to where the following code is "123".
        let ref = Database.database (). reference (). child ("123")

Answer (score 3):

You should really use a delegate in this case, something like

Read more about delegates [Here](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)

```
protocol MainTableViewControllerDelegate {
   func getChipFieldValue()
}


class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var delegate: MainTableViewControllerDelegate?

    // to get chipFieldValue self.delegate?.getChipFieldValue)
}
```

In LoginViewController define the function in delegate

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController,MainTableViewControllerDelegate { 

func getChipFieldValue() ->String {
   return chipField.text
}

// later in the code when you present MainTableViewController view pass delegate to self  to MainTableViewController object
// something like the MainTableViewControllerObject.delegate = self


}
```

Comment: Please note OP's comment in presenting a Navigation Controller with MainTableViewController as root. This method may result in retain cycle

Comment: Do you know How to define delegate in swift? You have to do the same way like this to call the UIInputField

Comment: return chipField.text
// error : Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String' @user1376400